# how to control (show & hide) the tooltip dynamically in google chart api?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using google chart api for my web application. i have to show & hide tooltip dynamically in that chart. For showing the tooltip

```
 tooltip: {
     trigger: 'selection',
     textStyle: {
         fontName: 'Arial',
         fontSize: 12,
         bold: true
     }
 },
 // listener 
 var globalId;
 google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function (args) {
     if (chart.getSelection().length > 0) {
         var selection = chart.getSelection()[0];
         var annotationTextXAxis = chartData.getValue(selection.row, 0);
         var annotationTextYAxis = chartData.getValue(selection.row, 1);
         $("#popupDatepicker").datepicker({
             yearRange: globalId + ':' + globalId
         }).val();
         globalId = annotationTextXAxis;
         inputAnnotation();
     }
 });
```

but in this method, tooltip showed when i click data point and hide only when i click again that data point or another data point. I need to hide that showed tooltip if suppose i clicked somewhere else in that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a click event handler for the `<body>` that tests whether the click target is a descendant of the chart or not.  If it is not, clear the chart's selection:

```
function clearSelection (e) {
    if (!document.querySelector('#myChartDiv').contains(e.srcElement)) {
        myChart.setSelection();
    }
}
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', clearSelection);
}
else if (document.attachEvent) {
    document.querySelector('body').attachEvent('onclick', clearSelection);
}
```